# Overflow of columns inside box not working

Tags: html, css, overflow, multiple-columns, bulma

I'm using Chrome, and I can't get these two columns to overflow with a scrollbar inside the box. Instead, they flow past the box.

I've tried messing around with heights, setting overflow: auto/scroll properties on all of the different elements at each level, nothing seems to work.

Here's a codepen of the issue:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqxOBV

```
.sidebar-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I expect the columns to be contained inside the parent box, and a scrollbar to be visible for that column when the next flows past the containing box.

Edit: I'm trying to create two separate scrollbars, one for the left column and one for the right column.

Comment: Questions need to be primarily self-contained, so that the breakage or modification of an external link does not affect the readability of the question, so provide a [mcve] within as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y: scroll;` to `.box` instead of `.sidebar-list`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj7gsz65/)

Answer (score 0):

Make position `relative` for `parent-main` and `absolute` for `child-settings` elements. Apply `overflow: auto;height:100%` to the `child` elements to overflow.

```
/*parent*/
    .main {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px
    }

/*child*/
    .settings {
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%
    }
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px
}

.settings {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container settings" style="position: absolute;">
    <div class="box no-box-small-mobile">
      <div class="column">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container settings" style="position: absolute;">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="label">A thing</div>
      <div class="value">1.45</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I was looking for. I'm trying to create two separate overflow scrollbars for each column.

Comment: @jrichie911 Please check the updated answer. Please upvote and accept my answer if it had helped you.

Answer (score 0):

actually `.sidebar-list` not getting any calculated height value.

so you can do 2 thing

1. add `overflow-y: auto;` with `.box`
   `<div class="box no-box-small-mobile" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">`
2. add `max-height: 400px;` in `.sidebar-list`

```
.sidebar-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```